# PHP replace and/or remove bytes from text file

Tags: php, text, byte

Is there any way to remove or replace specific bytes from a text file without having to rewrite the entire file?  if I know the byte position of the text I want to remove or replace, is this possible?  I use `file_get_contents("file.txt",NULL,NULL,2,10)` to get data from a specific byte position, now I would like to remove and/or replace bytes in the same fashion. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *replace* individual bytes by simply seeking and writing to the appropriate location. You cannot, however, *remove* bytes without rewriting all the following bytes of the file. This answer is generally true for how computers store files, and is not specific to PHP.